# Binding to a second property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two properties in my viewmodel, called `Premises` and `Towns`.
I'm binding my ListViewItems to `Premises`, and in the itemtemplate I want to bind to `Towns`, but when I use the following XAML it tries to bind to `Premises.Towns` instead of `Towns`.

How can I bind to `Towns` directly?

**Viewmodel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Premise> Premises;
    public List<Town> Towns;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
    <ListView x:Name="PremisesList" Margin="195,35,10,10"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource OverviewListViewItemStyle}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Premises}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

And this is what's in my `OverviewListViewItemStyle`.

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Towns}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

I'd like to be able to select a `Town` for a `Premise` via XAML.

Comment: Where is the problem? It does not display `Towns` or you don't know how to select `Town` for a `Premise`?

Comment: @dkozl I don't get to see any `Towns` in my combobox. I suspect it is because WPF is looking for the `Premises.Towns` property, which doesn't exist and thus shows no data.

Comment: @dkozl Do you also happen to know the steps to take so that I can easily select a Town for a Premise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption. `ComboBox` looks for `Towns` in `Premise` class, which is the class behind each `ListViewItem` If you want to refer to same context as `ListView` you need to use `RelativeSource` binding.

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.Towns}" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Not related to your problem but you also don't need to specify `DataTemplate` to display single property. `DisplayMemberPath` will work as well. If you do specify `DataTemplate` you don't need to use `ComboBoxItem` as `ComboBox` will wrap `DataTemplate` content in `ComboBoxItem` so effectively you'll end up with `ComboBoxItem` inside another `ComboBoxItem`

Comment: Indeed, that does the trick. Thanks for your quick help! Now to figure out the performance problems with displaying >2500 items.

Comment: Do you see any performance issues with 2500+ items in `ComboBox`?

Comment: I see a 5 - 7 second delay between clicking the combobox and seeing the items.

Comment: It's because `ComboBox` does not support virtualization so it will first create `ComboBoxItem` for each item in your collection

Comment: Is there a control that does allow virtualization that does the same?

Answer (score 1):

You bind the ItemsSource to the Premises property therefore if you bind to the Towns in the OverviewListViewItemStyle the binding engine will look up in the Premise object for a property called Towns.
If you want to select a town for a premises you should tell to the combobox where to look from that property. You can try to set the combobox's datacontext to the main viewmodel with relative source in the binding. Something like that:
`ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.Towns}"`